# Angular application uploaded without www works fine but when using www with domain. Chrome give cors policy error

Tags: angular, dns, hosting

I have an Angular application that i am able to upload to the hosting server. When creating the application build for i used
ng build --aot --prod --base-href=/ --deploy-url=https://example.org/

Now when i try to access the site with example.org, there is no issue. However, when I try to use [www.example.org](http://www.example.org), i get CORS policy error. I have asked the domain provider to look in to it but they say it is code related. I am not sure how to get [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) and the example.org to work.

I did try to create a package with
ng build --aot --prod --base-href=/ --deploy-url=https://www.example.org/
and still get the cors error. when i look further it seems like it is creating polyfills, runtime, etc without www as seen below

```
  </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.org/styles.50135e7d1237dabb.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.org/styles.50135e7d1237dabb.css">
    </noscript>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="https://example.org/runtime.61e1e587ce75c6f7.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="https://example.org/polyfills.66f3b77ed04b66c1.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="https://example.org/scripts.cf497f78bf937e66.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://example.org/main.d3a9a8f0f4096447.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

I want it to work with both url. with www and without it

Comment: I believe you don't need --deploy-url in your case. just build the project without it

Comment: @Andrei yes, that is what i ended up doing.